# While connecting with postgreSQL facing challenge with .net applicarion while establishing connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql

While getting data from postgresql database facing the error that is displaying in image.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserLogin(LoginModel login)
{
    string connString = "HOST = 172.18.0.202; PORT = 5432; DATABASE = MRSAC; PASSWORD = MRSACGEOTAG@123; USER ID = MRSACGEOTAG";

    try
    {
        NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
        string query = "select  userlogin,password from \"MRSACGEOTAG\".\"loginadminmaster\" where userlogin ='" + login.userlogin + "' and password ='" + login.password + "'  ";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        NpgsqlDataAdapter ngpsqlAdp = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        NpgsqlDataReader dr;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            con.Close();
            //return View("Create");
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.userlogin,false);
            return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Dashboard");
        }
        else
        {
            con.Close();
            ViewBag.errmsg = "Not valid Credentials";
        }

        return View("LandingPage");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
}
```

I am facing this error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

InnerException: InvalidOperationException: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.

I tried updating postgreSQL -version but its facing same issue.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

The error message `exception was thrown by the target of invocation` is a general error that doesn't provide specific details about what caused the exception, you have to look at the [InnerException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.innerexception?view=net-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_Exception_InnerException) property of the exception object, this will give you the actual exception that was thrown, with a more useful stack trace.

Also concatenating strings to form SQL queries is highly discouraged due to the risk of SQL injection attacks. Instead, use parameterized queries to prevent this vulnerability.

Comment: In InnerException is showing : InvalidOperationException: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.

Comment: Follow `@Filburt` first comment.